# How to delete break lines on JSON between rows when printing it in a web browser in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Javascript I have to print in the document a JSON with some data from MySQL database and I want to remove the break lines but I cannot achieve it.

I get the data through node.js and I use express.js for printing it on a web browser.
This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, there is a break line between both rows and I want to remove it since it is causing issues when I try to read the JSON on the android application I am building.

I have tried to search on internet about how to achieve it, most answers were about using `str.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '')` but it did not work in my case.

This is the JS code I currently have:

```
var dbData = '<%-usersList%>';
dbData = JSON.parse(dbData.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ''));
document.write(JSON.stringify(dbData));
```

And this is how I pass the data from node.js:

```
app.get('/dbJSON', function (req, res) {  
    getDBData().then((data) => {
        res.render('./dbJSON.ejs', {
            usersList: JSON.stringify(data.usersList)
        });
    });
});
```

This function calls the js file that gets the data from the db:

```
function getDBData() {
    const users = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbConnection
        .getUsers()
        .then(data => {
            resolve(data)
        })
    });
    const groups = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbConnection
        .getGroups()
        .then(data => {
            resolve(data)
        })
    });
    const frmTexts = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbConnection
        .getFrmTexts()
        .then(data => {
            resolve(data)
        })
    });
    return Promise.all([users, groups, frmTexts])
    .then(data => {
        return {
            usersList: data[0],
            groupsList: data[1],
            frmTextsList: data[2]
        }        
    });
}
```

Result of printing out data.usersList (in node.js):

[image]

Edit: Fixed! The reason of why I wanted to delete the break lines was because I had issues with parsing the JSON on Android Studio but I have just figured out it was due to I did not add the `http:/` in the url string (my bad). Now my android app is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Adrian2895,

Simply convert it to string and this will remove new-line/carriage-return. And also the above code is working fine (which I referred to use deep-cloning to remove any attribute).

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have been busy with other stuff. I have just tried again and nope, I do not know why it does not work in my case: https://i.imgur.com/NvcvvTL.png You can check the whole code I have in my JS file: https://i.imgur.com/XGWHNbE.png. Result in Chrome: https://i.imgur.com/m2Mwypn.png and: https://i.imgur.com/qSEpVvZ.png

Comment: Hi again. Apparently I do not need this anymore, so do not worry. The reason of why I wanted to delete the break lines was because I had issues with parsing the JSON on Android Studio but I have just figured out it was due to I did not add the ```http:/``` in the url string (my bad). Now my android app is working. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of deep cloning to get rid of unwanted attributes from JSON obj.

```
var rawData = [{ 
                    'iduser':1,
                    'user':'XXX',
                    'password': 'XXX123',
                    'groups_idgroup': 1,
                    'idgroup':1,
                    'name': 'James'
                },
                { 
                    'iduser':9,
                    'user':'XXX',
                    'password': 'XXX123',
                    'groups_idgroup': 2,
                    'idgroup':2,
                    'name': 'James'
                }];

rawData.forEach( function(item, index){
        rawData[index]  = Object.assign({}, item, {'user':undefined, 'password':undefined, 'name': undefined} );

console.log(JSON.stringify(rawData));
```

Output:-

```
[{"iduser":1,"groups_idgroup":1,"idgroup":1},{"iduser":9,"groups_idgroup":2,"idgroup":2}]
```

Comment: Oh no, no. I have censored user, password and name for privacy reason as it is data that I prefer not to show here in StackOverflow. So, I do not want to remove them from the JSON object. Sorry if it confused you. I just want to remove the break lines between both rows. Will your code work for this too?

Comment: btw: I have tried your code and there's an error. Visual Studio Code says ```'}' expected```. Check the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/jT7MyGF.png